# JavaFX stage issue with hide and show

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

Im building an application that shows a window that ask the user if he want to suspend the computer with two button options, one of them its a YES and the PC suspends.

The other button named "Later" supposed to hide the window and after an hour it appears again and ask the same question.

Code for the "later  buttton"

```
 noButton.setOnAction(event -> {


        Done=false; //boolean to close and open the frame
        Gui gui = new Gui();

            try {
                gui.start(classStage);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        });
```

The boolean that you see in the code is bc it was the way i think i could control that, trust me i tried in different ways but no one just help me with the issue, here is the code of the GUI class

```
public class Gui extends Application {

public  Stage classStage = new Stage();

public static boolean Done=true;

public static boolean flag=true;


public Gui() {


}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    Done = Controller.isDone();
    classStage = primaryStage;


    Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    primaryStage.setX(primaryScreenBounds.getMaxX() - primaryScreenBounds.getWidth());
    primaryStage.setY(primaryScreenBounds.getMaxY() - primaryScreenBounds.getHeight());
    primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainWindow.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Alerta suspencion de equipo");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

    if (Controller.isDone() == true) {
        primaryStage.show();

    } else if(Controller.isDone() == false) {
        primaryStage.hide();
         Platform.exit(); // this is the only way that the windows close 


    }
}
```

i know that Platform.exit(); kills the program but when i only use .hide(); of the Stage nothing happens, the window never closed, the worst part is that when i use the Platform.exit() command i cant make the frame appear again...

Anyone knows a way maybe easier to hide and show a window after certain time? maybe im doing this wrong.

Regards.

Comment: You can use a `Thread` or a `PauseTransition` . The second is recommended.

Comment: Why are you instantiating an `Application` subclass? Presumably you already have another `Application` subclass, since your JavaFX application is already running. You should only ever have one `Application` instance in a JavaFX program, and it should be the one created for you when you launch the FX application.

Comment: It's not clear why `classStage.hide()` is not working: that is unrelated to the code you have posted. Create a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem and [edit] your question to include it. You should be able to write a complete example with the functionality you've described (two buttons, etc) in just a few dozen lines of code, which is well within acceptable limits for a question here.

Comment: Ok, i will do that just give me a minute. @James_D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what's going on in the code in your question. The bottom line is that you should never create an instance of `Application` yourself; the only `Application` instance should be the one created for you.

I don't actually see any need to have a separate class for the functionality you've shown (though you could, of course). All you need to do is hide `classStage` if the no button is pressed, and open it again in an hour:

```
noButton.setOnAction(event -> {


    Done=false; //boolean to close and open the frame

    classStage.hide();
    PauseTransition oneHourPause = new PauseTransition(Duration.hours(1));
    oneHourPause.setOnFinished(e -> showUI(classStage));
    oneHourPause.play();
}); 

// ...

private void showUI(Stage stage) {

    Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    stage.setX(primaryScreenBounds.getMaxX() - primaryScreenBounds.getWidth());
    stage.setY(primaryScreenBounds.getMaxY() - primaryScreenBounds.getHeight());
    stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainWindow.fxml"));
    stage.setTitle("Alerta suspencion de equipo");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    stage.show();
}
```

Note that the FX Application will exit if the last window is closed, by default. So you should call `Platform.setImplicitExit(false);` in your `init()` or `start()` method.

I am assuming you are reloading the FXML file because the UI might have changed since it was previously loaded. Obviously if that's not the case, all you have to do is show the stage again as it is:

```
noButton.setOnAction(event -> {


    Done=false; //boolean to close and open the frame

    classStage.hide();
    PauseTransition oneHourPause = new PauseTransition(Duration.hours(1));
    oneHourPause.setOnFinished(e -> classStage.show());
    oneHourPause.play();
});
```

Comment: actually one of the biggest problems with is that the method classStage.hide doesn't work, the stage never hide.

Comment: @ChristopherAngel Then something else is wrong in your code, essentially separate from everything you have posted.